# PHP preg_split &Acirc;&nbsp; [0-9] &Acirc;&nbsp;

Tags: php, preg-split

Hi i need to split a string into an array based on this "dynamic" separator:

```
String &Acirc;&nbsp; 1&Acirc;&nbsp; String2

String2 &Acirc;&nbsp; 65&Acirc;&nbsp; String3
```

The number between the  `&Acirc;&nbsp;` it's variable... also the strings could contain `&Acirc;&nbsp;` too, so a str_replace or an explode it's useless (for me)

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please post the code what you have done so far. This is not a "please give me the code" site albeit you have a good chance when asking a regex question to get the code anyway. So if someone gives you a regex, please ask for an explanation.

Comment: Make us clear with your question to fix your problem

Answer (score 0):

```
$str = "String &Acirc;&nbsp; 1&Acirc;&nbsp; &Acirc;&nbsp;";
$result = preg_split('/ &Acirc;&nbsp; [\d]+&Acirc;&nbsp; /', $str);
print_r($result);

Array
(
    [0] => String
    [1] => &Acirc;&nbsp;
)
```

Explanation:

```
# Match the characters “ &Acirc;&nbsp; ” literally « &Acirc;&nbsp; »
# Match a single digit 0..9 «[\d]+»
#    Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) «+»
# Match the characters “&Acirc;&nbsp; ” literally «&Acirc;&nbsp; »
```